# TYPO3 - PHP errors after server restart

Tags: typo3, restart, php

We had to restart a server that has a TYPO3 site on it. We made no changes to the database of any of the TYPO3 files themselves, just a standard restart. The issue is that now the server is spewing php errors. I would like to stress that no server configuration changes were made.

A sample of our error logs:

```
[Wed Jun 27 23:55:19 2012] [error] [client ****************] PHP Strict Standards:  
Declaration of tx_commerce_db_article::get_attributes() should be compatible with tx_commerce_db_alib::get_attributes($uid, $attribute_corelation_type_list = '') 
in /var/www/html/***********/class.tx_commerce_db_article.php on line 63
```

Anyone have any ideas of what might have cause typ03 to make a deposit on the living room rug?

The server will take the request but admin page and main page will not display.

Comment: Did you update the `tx_commerce` (or other extensions) some time ago and did you forget to clear the cache?

Comment: i tried clearing the cache :(

Comment: Someone upgraded the PHP and Apache version of the box :(

Answer (score 1):

Someone updated PHP to version 5.4 on the server. Only the latest dev versions in the git repositories include a fix to the display error pattern that explicitly excludes `E_STRICT`.

Have a look at this issue and the according patches:
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/35154